# create xml from object without setting values in it c#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to convert a c# class to an xml file without declaring default values in it. If I declare values on every propery in the class I got it to work and the XML has all the properties in it. The primarydata is my class with properties in it.

```
 var pD = new PrimaryData();
 XmlSerializer serializerPrimaryData = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PrimaryData));
 serializerPrimaryData.Serialize(File.Create(xmlLocation), pD,ns);
```

But I dont want to declare any values.

If i run this code I get just:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<PrimaryData />
```

I don't get the properties in the class as you can see. So how can I get the properties in the class without declaring them to a default value?
Any suggestions?

I have followed this guide: https://codehandbook.org/c-object-xml/
But he is declaring default values to his class.

```
public class PrimaryData
{
    public PrimaryData();

    public string BatchId { get; set; }
    public CurrentOperation CurrentOperation { get; set; }
    public Heat Heat { get; set; }
    public string MaterialId { get; set; }
    public List<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
    public OrderInfo OrderInfo { get; set; }
    public Plate Plate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you show us your PrimaryData class code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set default values.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var employee = new Employee();
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    var se = new XmlSerializer(employee.GetType());
    var tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
    se.Serialize(tw, employee);
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
    Console.Read();
}
```

Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <FirstName />
    <LastName />
</Employee>
```

Second solution is to set `XmlElement(IsNullable = true)`

```
public class Employee
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But I dont want to set the default values. Is there a way to do it without set default values?

Comment: or use this XmlElement(IsNullable = true). I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you! I will check this

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue what you are trying to do ...

XML serialization just makes a mirror of the object in different structure (aka XML - object will be represented by structured text).

If your class has no properties, nothing will be serialized to XML but only the base empty object.

My suggestion is to make a class with `Dictionary<string, object>` as property. Then you will be able to write into the Dictionary and serialize it.

But, it has some drawbacks. XML Serialization (if I remember correctly) does not support Dictionaries, so I would go with `DataContract` instead.

That might work :)

```
[DataContract]
public class PrimaryData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Data", Order = 0, IsRequired = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Convert a class to xml.
`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PrimaryData>
  <MaterialId>0</MaterialId>
  <BatchId>0</BatchId>
  <Plate>
    <PlateLength>0</PlateLength>
    <PlateWidth>0</PlateWidth>
    <PlateThick>0</PlateThick>
    <PlateWeight>0</PlateWeight>
    <NonRectangular>false</NonRectangular>
    <LotNo>0</LotNo>
    <HeatTreatmentResourceCode>0</HeatTreatmentResourceCode>
    <Prio>0</Prio>
    <PackageNo>0</PackageNo>
  </Plate>
</PrimaryData>`

I want it to be like that.

Comment: You will then just populate Dictionary like this:

var primaryData = new PrimaryData();
primaryData.Data["BatchId"] = 0;
primaryData.Data["MaterialId"] = 0;

and so on.

You might want to take a look at [CollectionDataContract] attribute, so you can customize your XML.

Comment: I have properties in my class, but I dont want to set a default value to them. See my edit question.

Comment: Thats exactly what I do  `var pD = new PrimaryData();
 XmlSerializer serializerPrimaryData = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PrimaryData));
 serializerPrimaryData.Serialize(File.Create(xmlLocation), pD,ns);`

Comment: I saw. But you don't have to do that way. In corporal environment, there are a lots of classes that are "dynamic-like", without strongly-typed structure

Comment: But if the class changes, that means I have to add primaryData.Data["NewProperty"] = 0?

Comment: Yep. Or use config file with predefined items. Sometimes, XSLT transformation is used for this.

But still, it does not matter from where you populate Dictionary. You have positive thing that you don't have to change your class each time you add new property. Also (and be careful), serializer does not check whether the value is in dictionary. It might not be there, if you do not populate it.

Comment: Also, take a note, that each object ALWAYS have default value. Does not matter whether it's ValueType (aka Int32 and default value of 0) or Reference type (aka System.Object and default value of `null`).

you can always use `default(typeof(YourType))` to get default value.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this annotation to your properties:

```
[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
public string Prop { get; set; }
```

The result in your xml should be something like this:

```
<Prop xsi:nil="true" />
```